# javascript code not working with html script

Tags: javascript, html

hi guys I just begin to learn javascript recently and I came across an issue, when I enter a "10" as the first input element and click submit, it should print a "10" at the bottom of the html page, but instead it prints nothing.

```
<html>
<head>
<head>

  <form action="" method="POST" id="info">

      <br>Age:<br><label>
        <input name="age" id="age" type="text" placeholder= "enter your age" />
      </label>

      <br>Sex:<br><label>
        female<input name="female" id="female" type="checkbox"  />|
        male<input type="checkbox" name="male" id="male"   />|
      </label>

      <br>weight:<br><label>
        <input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" placeholder="enter your weight in kg"  />   
      </label>

      <input type="submit" form="info" value="Submit" onclick="validation()"/>
  </form>
  <div id="div1"> </div>
<script src = "test.js"></script>
<html>
```

This is the html code (index.html)

```
function validation(){
    var ageinput = parseInt(document.getElementById("age"));
    var femaleinput = ducument.getElementById("female");
    var maleinput = ducument.getElementById("male");
    var weight = parseInt(document. getElementById("weight"));
    var formulaformale;
    var formulaforfemale;
    var gendererror;
    if (ageinput == 10){
        gendererror = ageinput
    }
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = gendererror;
}
```

this is the javascript code.(test.js)

I tried to find syntax errors but everything looks fine to me, I also compared my code with other people's and I could find anything in my code that is different.I am totally new in javascript so I might have missed certain part of the programming language. please help.

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button type is submit, so it will always submit and reload the page every time you press the button. Make it a normal button by changing input type to `button`

```
<input type="button" form="info" value="Submit" onclick="validation()"/>
```

Then follow @Ibra answer

```
// add .value
var ageinput = parseInt(document.getElementById("age").value);

// ducument -> document 
var femaleinput = ducument.getElementById("female").value;
```

Comment: The `<form>` tag in this example isn't even necessary. Along with the input type change from "submit" to "button", you could also remove the `<form>` tags to prevent this issue in the future (unless, of course, you actually want to submit form data to a server).

Answer (score 1):

Try again like this :

```js
// add .value
   var ageinput = parseInt(document.getElementById("age").value);

// ducument -> document 
 var femaleinput = ducument.getElementById("female").value;
```